# Trajectory of a particle moving outwards in a circular force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

If we put a little stick through a ring, extend our arm holding the stick, and start twisting (we perform circular motion), then the ring will move outwards until it falls from the stick.

What is the trajectory followed by the ring, from an observer that stares from above? I believe that we may assume that the force exerted to the ring by the stick is always tangent to the circle, so I think our observer would describe the force as $\vec {F} = (y,-x)$.

Then,
$$m \ddot {x} = y$$
$$m \ddot {y} = -x$$

And here I get stuck. How could  I get the trajectory equation?

Comment: Hint: Use polar coordinates for simplicity.

Comment: Is the rod rotated with a uniform velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: It isn't mentioned in the question, but im going to assume the rod is rotated with a constant angular velocity $\omega$

The acceleration in the radial direction is:

$\ddot r = \omega ^2 r$

$\therefore \dot r d\dot r = \omega ^2 r dr$

$\therefore \int_0^{\dot r} \dot r d\dot r = \omega ^2 \int_{r_0}^r r dr$

$\therefore \frac{\dot r ^2}2 = \omega ^2 \frac {r^2 - r_0 ^2}2$

$\therefore \frac {dr}{\sqrt{r^2 - r_0 ^2}} = \omega dt$

$\therefore \int_{r_0}^r\frac {dr}{\sqrt{r^2 - r_0 ^2}} = \omega \int_0^t dt$

$\therefore ln \left| \frac {r + \sqrt{r^2 - r_0 ^2}}{r_0} \right| = \omega t$
.................(Substitute $cos(u) = \frac {r_0}r$)

Since $\omega$ is constant, we know that $\theta = \omega t$

$$\therefore ln \left| \frac {r + \sqrt{r^2 - r_0 ^2}}{r_0} \right| = \theta$$

You can use the relations ($r = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$) and ($ tan \theta = \frac yx)$ to convert to linear coordinates