# According to inertial frame, how can a bead move in a groove made on a rotating table?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, rotation

**Context:**

Consider a **smooth** circular table rotating uniformly. Along it's radius , a groove is made. While it's rotating , a bead is placed on the groove **gently** at some distance (say $x$) from centre. We need to find it's speed when it reaches a distance $L$ ($L>x$) from the centre.

Here's a figure depicting the situation : [image]

I have already solved the problem by considering the rotating frame and pseudo force.

**Problem:**

However, I can't imagine that how this motion would even occur according to lab or inertial frame. According to inertial frame, the bead should move in a spiral way because it's coming out of groove as well as rotating with table.

But the only horizontal forces acting on bead is normal forces by walls of groove , which are along the perpendicular to the radius vector joining bead and centre !  Since , $\cos(90°)=0$ this force has no component parallel to radius vector. So there is neither any centripetal force acting on the bead to make it rotate nor any force to make it come out of groove ! So , how can this motion occur according to inertial frame ?

I'm looking for an intuitive explanation that how can ball even move in such a manner. There's a similar question but it's answer is not understandable by me.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/584107/how-can-there-be-radial-acceleration-without-any-radial-force

Comment: A statement like “There's a similar question but its answer is not understandable by me” is not helpful. Link to the question and explain why it is not understandable. Also, if it is a different question than the one listed as duplicate above, also explain what you need that is not in those answers

Comment: @Dale According to the duplicate linked answer, the book is wrong and the particle cannot go in circular motion. But from rotating frame, it's definitely possible that it can go in rotation because the pseudo force make it works.

Comment: @An_Elephant, if the bead is moving in the groove, then it can't be in circular motion.  That would require it to be at the same point in the groove (same distance from the center) at all times.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I never said it will be in a uniform circular motion. I said it will move something like a spiral. Please read the question again. Also please answer my question.