Why do you get pushed out in the merry go round (should you not be the same distance from the centre)?
If you look at a merry-go-round from the inertial frame and see a person distance $r$ away from the centre as the merry-go-round spins about its origin why is the person pushed back? As in the inertial frame (looking from outside the merry-go-round) the person should not move and remain at the same point and therefore as the merry-go-round spins around the person will always maintain a distance $r$ from the merry-go-round.
Edit: The merry-go-round and person are in frictionless contact.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/584107/

@BowlOfRed I forgot to mention in the question that the contact between the merry-go-round surface and the person is frictionless, therefore shouldn't the person be at the same distance r away from the centre of the merry-go-round?
and how does friction change this, (If friction gives the person a tangential velocity  I can understand the moving back) But I don't understand why friction will result in tangential velocity. Is there a visual or diagram that explains that?

That would be an odd merry-go round.   Yes, if the floor is frictionless, then the person won't move at all in any direction (in the inertial frame).   The problem normally assumes there is some interaction between the object and the disk.

Please edit your question and add the point about the merry-go-round being frictionless.

friction will  create a tangential force because the floor is moving in such direction relative to the person located at r. Just imagine the extreme case of the person being glued to it.

If you don’t edit your post as requested by BowlIfRed so that it makes sense (which it doesn’t at present) I will vote to close

Are you assuming that the person is rotating around the center of the merry-go-round? If the contact is frictionless, what is causing this to happen?

If the merry-go-round is perfectly frictionless, then yes the person will remain in place and never move.
